# Using igraph for read 'ncol' format while preserving labels

Tags: python, igraph

I need an automated way to read 'ncol' format (edge list) ***while preserving labels.***

For instance:

Given a small-graph.edgelist:

```
0 1 0.47
0 2 0.67
0 3 0.98
0 4 0.12
0 5 0.82
0 10 0.34
1 2 0.94
1 3 0.05
1 4 0.22
2 3 0.24
2 4 0.36
3 4 0.69
5 6 0.97
5 8 0.44
5 7 0.43
5 9 0.37
6 7 0.83
6 8 0.49
6 9 0.55
7 8 0.39
7 9 0.73
8 9 0.68
10 11 0.22
10 14 0.59
11 12 0.40
12 13 0.78
13 14 0.81
```

Graph:

[image]

I try:

```
import igraph
g = igraph.read("smallgraph.edgelist", format="ncol", directed=False, names=True)
```

But this function does not preserve the labels!!!!

The output generated by this function:

```
for edge in g.es():
    print edge.tuple[0], edge.tuple[1], edge["weight"]

0 1 0.47
0 2 0.67
0 3 0.98
0 4 0.12
0 5 0.82
0 6 0.34 -> e.g.: Considering the original labels here should be '0 10 0.34'
1 2 0.94
1 3 0.05
1 4 0.22
2 3 0.24
2 4 0.36
3 4 0.69
5 7 0.97
5 8 0.44
5 9 0.43
5 10 0.37
6 11 0.22
6 12 0.59
7 8 0.49
7 9 0.83
7 10 0.55
8 9 0.39
8 10 0.68
9 10 0.73
11 13 0.4
12 14 0.81
13 14 0.78
```

Output:

[image]

The labels of the input file (small-graph.edgelist) are not preserved.

I think something like this could work:

```
g = igraph.Graph()
g.add_vertices(15)
g = igraph.read("input/small-graph.edgelist", format="ncol", directed=False, names=True)
```

But this doesn't work and I don't know how to do it.
Does anyone know how to preserve the original labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original labels are preserved, but they are stored in the `name` vertex attribute. Try this after reading your graph as usual:

```
names = g.vs["name"]
for edge in g.es:
    print names[edge.tuple[0]], names[edge.tuple[1]], edge["weight"]
```

**Update**: If you are absolutely sure that your file contains only *continuous* numeric IDs from zero (i.e. if you have *n* vertices then your IDs are from zero to *n*-1), you can do the following:

```
edges, weights = [], []
for line in open("input_file.txt"):
    u, v, weight = line.split()
    edges.append((int(u), int(v)))
    weights.append(float(weight))
g = Graph(edges, edge_attrs={"weight": weights})
```

Comment: Thanks. But there is no way to preserve the ids? E.g.: init `g = igraph.Graph(15)`, next read file (edge list)!!

Answer (score 2):

Just a little improvement based on updated answer of Tamás' for the case that the file contains only continuous numeric IDs from zero. This works for directed graphs and handles some cases such as there might be no edge from 0 to any other vertices:

```
read_edges(num_vertices,input_graph):
   g = Graph(directed=True)
   g.add_vertices(list(range(0,num_vertices)))
   for line in open(input_graph):
      u, v= line.split()
      g.add_edge(int(u), int(v))
   return g
```